# React: Why does my array appear empty in console.log() before being populated with API values?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component where I'm making an API call to fetch user data, and I've noticed that when I log the data using console.log(), the array initially appears empty and then gets populated with values from the API. if I try to access the 'usertype' property using console.log(UserMasterDataGlobal[0]?.usertype) this leads to an error during the initial load, stating 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'usertype')'. It seems like the data isn't available during the first attempt.

I have tried using useEffect to fetch the data and update the state (UserMasterDataGlobal). I've also tried conditional rendering based on the usertype property from the fetched data. However, the issue persists where the array initially logs as empty, causing the mentioned error.

I suspect that there might be a timing issue or an asynchronous behavior causing the array to log empty initially. I am seeking guidance on how to ensure that the array is populated with values from the API before attempting to access and use those values in my component.

Additionally, please note that I am relatively new to React, so any explanation in simpler terms or beginner-friendly suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function Navbar1() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // const usernameglobal='';
  
  const Redirectif = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      navigate('/LoginPage');
    }, []);
  }

  const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState({});
  
  // const Getusermasterglobaldata = () => {
  //   useEffect(() => {
  //     // Fetch data from the specified URL
      
  //     const response = axios.get('http://localhost/apiline/UserMaster/getdatabyusername?username='+usernameglobal)
  
  //       .then((response) => {
  //         setUserMasterDataGlobal(response.data.UserMasterDataGlobal);
  //         })
  //         .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  //     }, []);
  // }

  const Getusermasterglobaldata = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          // Fetch data from the specified URL
          const response = await axios.get('http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/UserMaster/getdatabyusername?username=' + usernameglobal);
          setUserMasterDataGlobal(response.data.UserMasterDataGlobal);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
      };
  
      fetchData();
    }, [/* dependencies, if any */]);
  };  
  
  const usernameglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
  const usertimestampglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usertimestamp'));

  try {
    if (usertimestampglobal != null) {
      const parsedTimestamp = parseInt(usertimestampglobal, 10);
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const twelveHoursAgo = currentTime - (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 12 hours in milliseconds

      if (parsedTimestamp < twelveHoursAgo) {
        localStorage.removeItem('timestamp');
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        // Redirectif();
      }
    }
  }
  catch {

  }

  if(usernameglobal == null){
    Redirectif();
  }
  else{
    //2) using axios
    Getusermasterglobaldata();
  }

  console.log(UserMasterDataGlobal);
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Brand Name</h4>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        {/* <Navbar.Brand>Brand Name</Navbar.Brand> */}
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
        
          {UserMasterDataGlobal.usertype === "ADMIN" && (
            <NavDropdown title="Admin" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="/registration">Registration</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          )}
          
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That state value isn't an array, it's an object:

```
const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState({});
```

If it *should* be an array, make it one:

```
const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState([]);
```

(That's a big "if" though.  The question indicates that sometimes you expect it to be an array, and sometimes you expect it to be an object.  It's really up to you what data structure this should be and to be consistent with that.)

As for conditionally handling an empty object or array, [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can help with that.  For example, if the value is an object:

```
console.log(UserMasterDataGlobal?.usertype)
```

or if it's an array of objects:

```
console.log(UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.usertype)
```

You could also initialize the value to `undefined` to more explicitly determine when it exists or not:

```
const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState();
```

And in the markup check whether it exists:

```
{UserMasterDataGlobal && UserMasterDataGlobal.usertype === "ADMIN" && (
  <NavDropdown title="Admin" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    <NavDropdown.Item href="/registration">Registration</NavDropdown.Item>
  </NavDropdown>
)}
```

Or using optional chaining:

```
{UserMasterDataGlobal?.usertype === "ADMIN" && (
  <NavDropdown title="Admin" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    <NavDropdown.Item href="/registration">Registration</NavDropdown.Item>
  </NavDropdown>
)}
```

There are pretty much countless ways to structure it.  But overall the pattern comes down to:

1. Be consistent with your data structures.
2. If a value might be `null` or `undefined`, don't assume it isn't.  Check if the value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and/or use optional chaining before directly using the value.  (Whether that value is a variable, a property on an object, or an element in an array.)

Comment: Thank you, David. I applied the code UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.usertype, and now I am getting the desired output as I want. However, could you please explain why the value is printed twice in the console? It initially appears as 'undefined' and then displays the actual value. By the way, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Mr.Pvg: If you're logging the value to the console during the component render then it's going to log on every render of the component.  So first it will log the value based on the initial state, then after fetching the data and updating the state it will re-render and log the new value.